# How to create caches folder in gradle folder?

Tags: windows, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I am setting up gradle on my machine for the first time.

I have to create a REST based java project setup on my machine with gradle as build tool.

I have set the environment variable GRADLE_HOME to the folder where i have unzipped gradle 3.2.0.62-bootstrapper.

I have also set the environment variable GRADLE_OPTS to -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all

i have added GRADLE_HOME to Path variable. The OS is windows 7.

Then I executed gradle -version in cmd of windows. It started downloading few dependencies.

Then I executed gradle installCerts .

In the spring tool suite, I am trying to create a variable GRADLE_REPOSITORY and it should point to caches folder in C:\Users\.gradle\caches.

But the caches folder is not created in .gradle folder.

Please let me know in which case the caches folder is created and what is the use of GRADLE_REPOSITORY in spring tool suite.

I am totally new to gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GRADLE_USER_HOME` is used to change the gradle user home folder that contains the caches and other metadata used by gradle. This is what you need to change.

`GRADLE_HOME` is supposed to point to the installation folder of Gradle.

In general I encourage you the Gradle wrapper which makes manual installation of Gradle obsolete and you would not need to deal with `GRADLE_HOME`.

Comment: but how does this caches folder get created?

Comment: the cache folder is created within the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` folder as required. usually by just running a gradle build this folder will be created as part of the build

Comment: GRADLE_REPOSITORY is nothing that Gradle itself respects in any way. That is a sts specific thing